# Python POST request gives unknown result

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, twitch

So I'm really out of my element with RESTful stuff. I'm trying to make a thing on that subscribes to an action/webhook(?) on twitch.tv so that if someone goes live, it knows.

I want to use this webhook here:

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/webhooks-reference/#topic-stream-changed

I made a Flask server in `server.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    print(request.data)
    return 'Received'
```

and the POST I make is over here in `notify.py`:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/webhooks/hub", headers={'Client-ID': client_id}, data={"hub.callback": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/","hub.mode":"subscribe",'hub.topic':"https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=XXXXXX"})
```

Running my code shows nothing on the server, not even `Received` so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

if I do a GET, on 
`request = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=xxxxxx', headers={'Client-ID': client_id})`

the result is `b ' '`

and I have no idea what that means

in `notifiy.py`, putting a `print(r)` returns `<Response [202]>` but I think I want a [200]

I assume my server needs to be reachable by Twitch to see it but I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you actually start your server? For example `app.run(host, port, debug, options)` Can you show the full code for `server.py` please? Also, what is the status code you are getting when you do your POST request?

Comment: @Silveris Yup! I did ```set FLASK_APP=server.py``` and it runs on ```127.0.0.1:5000```

Comment: either return a valid `html` or `json` and set `content-type` in the headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final EDIT...** I have created a [proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/vulcan25/9536fe940898545f3a9961a6037f2509)

---

You're POSTing `"hub.callback": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"`.  That URL is only accessible on your machine.

This is supposed to be a URL which is accessible from the Twitch infrastructure.  If you can't register a domain, then you could use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get a valid URI which routes back to your Flask development server for testing.

Once you have sent the POST request, you can [get the webhook subscriptions](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-webhook-subscriptions) to confirm the post request worked.  **This is also possible using `curl`**, with the commands included to the right of this documentation.

Assuming you see valid subscriptions there, then the endpoint you provide as `hub.callback` should receive a hit from Twitch...

> when a stream changes; e.g., stream goes online or offline, the stream title changes, or the game changes.

Within the route you'd then do some logic to deal with the result of that request.

---

**Update re comments**

You may wish to try updating `hub.lease_seconds`: [(here)](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/webhooks-reference/)

> Number of seconds until the subscription expires. Default: 0. Maximum: 864000.
>
> The default (0) allows you to test the subscription-creation workflow without creating any subscriptions (since they expire immediately). After testing, to actually create subscriptions, you must specify a larger value.

This belongs in the dictionary passed as the `data` argument to `requests.post` in `notify.py`:

Comment: okay so I set up the ngrok server and did this:

```r = requests.post("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/webhooks/hub", headers={'Client-ID': client_id}, data={"hub.callback": "http://XXX.ngrok.io","hub.mode":"subscribe",'hub.topic':"https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=XXX"})
```

but doing this: 
```print(r)``` just gives ```<Response [202]>```

Comment: That sounds correct.  `print (r.json())` to see the actual response payload.

Comment: ```print(r.json)``` prints ```<bound method Response.json of <Response [202]>>```

the ngrok server displays ```GET /                          200 OK   ``` as well which seems good, but checking the subscriptions still returns ```b'{"total":0,"data":[],"pagination":{}}'```

Comment: `r.json()` not `r.json` to return the dictionary.  Guessing the clue will be in the response of that initial hit to the "Topic: Stream Changed" endpoint, hence subscriptions being empty.

Comment: hmmm. weird. it returns an error: ```json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)```

the server posts ```"GET /?hub.challenge=Y2dYTcgN-fyNKA2PEiySd3ikIeEIEM-J81qSVaBy&hub.lease_seconds=0&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.topic=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitch.tv%2Fhelix%2Fstreams%3Fuser_id%xxx HTTP/1.1" 200``` I read that error might be from getting 400 errors, but I'm seeing a 200 on the server, and printing it still returns a [202]

Comment: if `r.json()` shows that decode error, instead `print(r.content)` to see what the server actually replied with.  It sounds like you may not be making that request correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200274/discussion-between-v25-and-aon).